# Need to insert JSON object into Angular.JS controller's scope

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

You don't need to know much about Java Server Pages to answer this question, it is only used to explain the context of the question and the limitations I am currently facing.

I am currently developing an application in Adobe AEM which uses Java Server Pages to render HTML content.  The client side part of the application uses an Angular.js framework.  I am currently in a conundrum while trying to use both Java Server Pages and HTML using the Angular.js framework.  I need to accomplish the following things:

1. On the Java Server Page, I only want to render the HTML that has to do with one angular.js controller - I cannot declare a full-fledged angular app inside of it, otherwise it would cause problems when interacting with other JSP.
2. I want to pass in a JSON object that I need for my Angular.JS controller to run correctly, but I can only retrieve this JSON object by using the "Java" portion of my Java Server Pages --  I cannot get the JSON object I need from the client side (or javascript portion) of things
3. The directive ng-init does allow me to put in a JSON object inside of the controller, but the object isn't available in the controller's $scope when it's first run.  I want to find a way to insert the JSON object into the tag containing the controller and have it available in its scope before its function starts to run.
4. I do not want to simply put a variable inside of a script tag so that the controller can find it before it runs - I can't have any global variables polluting the namespace, since many JSPs will be rendered on one given web page at a time.

Consider the following jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ttxmg4qd/

This is the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="foo2 = 'How to make this show up in $scope when MyCtrl is initialized for the first time?';">
{{foo2}}
</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.obj = { prop: "world" };
    $scope.foo = "foo";
    alert($scope.foo2); 
});
```

Note that I can't access the variable "foo2" when that controller function is first running when I use the ng-init directive.  It instead appears as "undefined" until it is evaluated with the {{foo2}} binding in the html.

How do I make it so that I pass a variable into the HTML and have it available to the controller's scope when it starts running?

Comment: I actually work with AEM & Angular on a daily basis. What is the reason for not mixing? We just have the angular app defined at a base template, and then if there is any angular directive it gets picked up on page load, otherwise it doesn't hurt anything to have an angular app defined and unused.

Comment: It's great that you have AEM experience, perhaps you can find a great way around this:

This JSP is meant to be rendered inside of a parsys of another AEM component.  If we declare another angular app inside of this, then it ends up giving us bootstrap errors on the client side.

Comment: This is just a JSP that's meant to be dragged inside of the parsys of a "container" object, which actually contains the angular app.  I want to avoid nested angular apps.

Comment: Is the JSP loaded as apart of a teaser? Or something that happens after initial page load? What we did was setup a .$watch('$viewContentLoaded') in a container controller, and then parse the html that is loaded for script tags, and then ran eval() on them. Maybe something along those lines will work for you?

If it's not loaded in a teaser, then I don't know what the issue is, maybe your angular-component defined as part of your app.js?

Comment: @kshreve, that sounds like it could work pretty well.  Would you be able to put that into a plnkr.co or a jsfiddle so I can see more clearly how that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject it as a global and access via `$window`

or you can use [angular-preloaded](https://github.com/garbles/angular-preloaded) to inject your variables in a script tag of `type="text/preloaded"` and have it available to your controller via `$preloaded` service.

Have your jsp output stuff like below

```
<script type="text/preloaded">
{
  "data": "point"
}
</script>
```

and get it in your controller like below

```
angular.module('app', ['gs.preloaded'])
.controller('SomeCtrl', function ($preloaded) {
    // do something with $preloaded.
    $preloaded; // => { data: "point", another: { point: "of data" } }
});
```

Remember to put your preloaded script before you controller script for this to work. From docs

> NOTE: Your script tags must run before anything using $preloaded, so I suggest putting them in your document's head.

Comment: I have tried this before:  this does solve the issue of exposing a JSON object to a controller before it is run for the first time, but at the cost of putting new variables in the global scope.  When I ran into the issue of multiple JSPs rendered into HTML fighting for that global variable, I realized that it wasn't a great long-term solution.  Thanks though.

Comment: This alternative does approach the idea that I am looking for.  I'm not in a physical position right now to actually test this alternative, but it does seem very promising.  I will upvote it for now, and I will accept this as the correct answer if it ends up being the best solution for my current situation.  Thank you.